# General integer roots $\sqrt[k]{n}$ approximating $\pi$

Tags: geometry, approximation, radicals, computational-mathematics, pi

Earlier today when I was playing around with one of my homebuilt numerical $k$:th-root-solvers, I found that the number $\sqrt[3]{31} = 3.14138\cdots \approx \pi$ . A quite good approximation to $\pi$, actually. I got curious if there are some results in general for how good approximations for $\pi$ one can get if one is limited to perform $$\sqrt[k]{n}, \hspace{1cm} k,n\in \mathbb N$$
Can we derive some bound in terms of $k$ and $n$ for how close we can get to $\pi$? Also, is it a coincidence that $n=2^m-1$ gives a good value for some $k,m$ or can we show that those $n$ are extra fruitful somehow? Anything is welcome, but I would guess that geometric arguments on a circle could be extra useful(?)

---

**EDIT** an even better approximation (correct decimal digits underlined) $$(31^4+748)^{1/12}= \underline {3.1415926}0 \cdots$$
Which was found by exploring
$$(31^k+n)^{1/(3k)}\cdots$$

However here the $n$ seems to in general get much larger, which is not so simple or elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aproximations can get as good as you want. In fact, it is easy to see that
$$A=\{\sqrt[k]n \in \mathbb R\colon n,k\in \mathbb N\}$$
is dense in $[1,\infty)$.

If we want to have
$$\alpha-\varepsilon<\sqrt[k]n<\alpha+\varepsilon$$
for $\alpha\ge1$ and $\varepsilon >0$, then we need $k$ and $n$ such that 
$$(\alpha-\varepsilon)^k<n<(\alpha+\varepsilon)^k.$$

Under our assumptions it can be proved that
$$(\alpha+\varepsilon)^k-(\alpha-\varepsilon)^k \to \infty$$
as $k \to \infty$, so in particular this difference can be made greater than one by taking $k$ large 
enough.

Let $k_0$ be such a value of $k$, then we must have some $n_0\in \mathbb N$ such that $(\alpha-\varepsilon)^{k_0}<n_0<(\alpha+\varepsilon)^{k_0}$ (for instance, at least one of $\left \lfloor (\alpha+\varepsilon)^{k_0} \right \rfloor$ and $\left \lceil (\alpha-\varepsilon)^{k_0} \right \rceil$ must work as such an $n_0$).

Then we have $$\alpha-\varepsilon<\sqrt[k_0]{n_0}<\alpha+\varepsilon$$ and since $\alpha\ge 1$ and $\varepsilon >0$ were arbitrary, it turns out that $A$ is dense in $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: No idea about your second question, though. Also, for a given $\alpha$ (in your case $\pi$) it would be interesting to look for "simple/nice" combinations of $n$ and $k$ given $\varepsilon$, and best approximation you can reach given conditions on $n$ and $k$.

Comment: By the way, my proof is somehow constructive, but nothing indicates that it will always give a "good/nice/simple" answer. Actually, it will usually make $k$ very large.

Comment: Yep, I guess it would be easy to prove that we can get arbitrarily close, but probably quite a challenge to show how to choose $k,n$ so that they both are the smallest in some sense for some given error.

Comment: What I see now is that $k$ never gets too big... and that's because taking $k$-th roots for $k$ even moderately large is a very 'strong' operation that takes large numbers very close to one. (For instance, the $10$-th root of $10^{10}$ is $10$, and for $100\,000$ is just $\sqrt{10}\simeq 3.16$. So it's actually $n$ which is hard to keep in low terms.

Comment: Yes it could be, but maybe the number remains easy to represent anyway. For example even for quite small $m$, $2^m-1$ becomes large, but still does not require much to represent. We can get away with storing the pair $(3,5)$ for the representation of $\sqrt[3]{2^5-1}$ above. Not so many bits.

Comment: The answer is again that you can achieve as much precision as desired (it's again a dense set), but I've been playing a while and now $k$ does get larger. Nothing extreme, but much larger than before.

Comment: Anyway, regarding $\pi$ alone, the aproximation you got is quite remarkable. $k=3$ and $m=5$ gives you an absolute error in the order of $2\times 10^{-4}$. Nevertheless, if you want to be just a bit closer to $\pi$ then you need $k=66$ and $m=109$.

Comment: Yes maybe I was not so right on the $2^m-1$ being a good side it seems $(31^4+748)^{1/12}= 3.14159260 \cdots$ for example. So maybe $(31^k+m)^{1/(3k)}$ is better.